# Yii2 How to save same file name but different file or content?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to save same name but different content for example, samplename.docx. Now i want to save it again but the result the same. When i create a new report and use the name samplename it will overwrite the other same name. So in the uploads folder the samplename.docx is only one. But in the dgView is more than one.

This is my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new reportDetails();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {      
        $project =$model->doc_name;
        $model->upload_file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
        $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
        $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->doc_name=$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->save();

        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data saved!');
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=> $model->report_id]);
    } 

    else {
        return $this ->render('create', [
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
public $upload_file;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['reference_no', 'subject', 'doc_for', 'doc_from', 'doc_date', 'doc_file', 'doc_name', 'drawer_id'], 'required'],
        [['doc_date'], 'safe'],
        [['drawer_id'], 'integer'],
        [['reference_no', 'doc_for', 'doc_from'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
        [['subject'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['doc_file', 'doc_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['user_id'],'string'],

    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'report_id' => 'Report ID',
        'reference_no' => 'Reference No:',
        'subject' => 'Subject:',
        'doc_for' => 'For:',
        'doc_from' => 'From:',
        'doc_date' => 'Document Entry Date:',
        'doc_file' => 'Document File:',
        'doc_name' => 'Document Name:',
        'drawer_id' => 'Drawer ID:',
        'user_id' => 'Encoder Name:',
    ];
}
```

And this is my form:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= Html::button('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Person', ['value' => Url::to('index.php?r=name/create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-custom-pos btn-success', 'id' => 'officialsfor']) ?>
        </br>  
        </br> 
  <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'for_from']) ?>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
     <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_for')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
           'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Name::find()->asArray()->all(),
            'name_id',
            function($model, $defaultValue){
              return $model['position'].' '.$model['fname'].' '.$model['mname'].' '.$model['lname'];
            }),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose a person ...'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
                'width' => 500,
             ],
            ]); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_from')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
           'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Name::find()->asArray()->all(),
           'name_id',
            function($model, $defaultValue){
            return $model['position'].' '.$model['fname'].' '.$model['mname'].' '.$model['lname'];
            }),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose a person ...'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
                'width' => 500,
            ],
            ]); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
      </div>
        </br>
        </br></br></br>
      <div class="broder" style=" border-radius: 5px; padding: 12px; ">    
      </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->textInput(['type' => 'hidden','style'=>'width:500px;','placeholder' => 'Enter a Reference No....','value' =>ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->middle_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name)]) ?>
       <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'user_id', ['label'=>ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->middle_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name),'style' => 'font-size: 21px;','class' => 'color']) ?>
      <br>
      <br>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'reference_no')->textInput(['style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Reference No....']) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'subject')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Subject....']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_date')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
            'inline' => false,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose a Entry Date ...'],
            'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
              ]
             ]);?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 14px; ">
         </br>
         </br>
         </br></br>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'drawer_id')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Drawer ID....', ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_name')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Document Name....']) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_file')-> widget(
        FileInput::classname(),[
      'name' => 'doc_file',
      'options' => ['accept' => '.docx','.doc','.docs'],
      'pluginOptions' => [
          'showPreview' => false,
          'showCaption' => true,
          'showRemove' => true,
          'showUpload' => false
            ]
        ]);
      ?>
```

Comment: So your goal is 1) To rename file if the file with the same name exist ?? Or
2) To stop overwritten with the same file name ??

Comment: Stop overwritten with the same file name sir.

Comment: make sure your CHMOD is 777

Comment: What is CHMOD ? and 777? i used windows 8 and xampp server.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(file_exists('...')){
   // upload file with , new file name
}
else{
   // upload file 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me a codes? i'm new with yii2 sir. I mean full codes according to my question.

Comment: it's not about Yii it's about php 

if(file_exist('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension){
$model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project . Yii::$app->generateRandomString(4) .'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
} else
{
$model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
}
this is for example you must see your need about this

Comment: Thank you but nothing happens.

Comment: PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Call to undefined function frontend\controllers\file_exist()   .. I got this error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (file_exists($fileFullPath)) { 
 unlink ($fileFullPath); 
 echo "delete existing file creating new <br />";
 }else{
  echo "file not exists creating new <br />"; 
}
```